# Is there a way to compare two columns and, if they match, get the data to the right of the cells to do an equation on?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, datatable, google-sheets-formula, calculated-columns

I am trying to automate something for work, but can't quite figure it out. I'm using Google Sheets for the data. Basically, I want to check if the Serial number in Column A match Column C, and if they do, to find the difference of the cost to the right of the Serial numbers. Is this possible? [Here's an example of what I'm trying to get as a result.->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNitN.png)

Also a note - the Serial numbers will include letters mixed in as well.

I've tried a bunch of different options using MATCH and QUERY but have hit dead ends and ERRORs

Answer (score 0):

```
=arrayformula(iferror((VLOOKUP(C2:C,A2:B,2,FALSE)-D2:D),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!